# A summation involving the absolute value of $\sin x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (n x)|}{n^2}$$ evaluate to?

Without the modulus, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29nx%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) says that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n x)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2} i\left(\mathrm{Li}_2\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$.

I have two questions:

1.) How did we get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n x)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2} i\left(\mathrm{Li}_2\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$?

2.) What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (n x)|}{n^2}$?

Thank you!

Comment: we can conclude that the given series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2}$ is convergent, and its sum is bounded above by $\frac{2\pi^2}{6}$, which simplifies to $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

Comment: How did you get that @user253963?

Comment: Since the terms involve absolute values, we know that $|\sin(nx)| \leq 1$ for any value of $x$.

Comment: Why the $2$ @user253963 ?

Comment: @user253963, can you please give a detailed solution as an answer? What you are saying makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is well-known to be equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Yes. But since $|\sin(nx)| \leq 1$, what about the values of less than 1 but greater than 0?

Comment: What user253963 did is just a standard comparison test between series with non-negative terms: $0 \leq \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ with the RHS being summable, thus the middle term is also summable and the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2} $ is lesser than the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: You could observe that the n=1 (possibly n <= 4) parts are a  very large part of the total sum and use this to improve the sum. |sin x| <= sum <= |sin x| + (pi^2 - 6) / 6 instead of 0 <= sum <= pi^2/6.

Comment: Guys, I think OP wants to know what the series with the absolute value evaluates to and not verify that the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, using the identities $\displaystyle{\sin(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}}$ and $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{i}=-i}$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}&=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-inx}}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{i}{2}\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-ix})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{ix})\right)}
\end{align*}$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ is the [Dilogarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) defined as,
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$$
for $|x|<1$.